# SQL Recursive Sub Query Factoring

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Consider a table with the below information.
**Table Data:**

| Code_ID | Name | Head_Name | Head_Rank | Report_To_Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | XYZ | 07 |  |
| 2 | DEF | BBB | 01 | 1 |
| 3 | GHI | ZZZ | 02 | 1 |
| 4 | JFK | XXX | 10 | 2 |

**Sample:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST_01 
   (  CODE_ID NUMBER(5), 
      NAME VARCHAR2(3), 
      HEAD_NAME VARCHAR2(3), 
      HEAD_RANK VARCHAR2(2), 
      REPORT_TO_CODE NUMBER(5)
   );
   
insert into test_01 (CODE_ID, NAME, HEAD_NAME, HEAD_RANK, REPORT_TO_CODE)
values (1, 'ABC', 'XYZ', '07', null);

insert into test_01 (CODE_ID, NAME, HEAD_NAME, HEAD_RANK, REPORT_TO_CODE)
values (2, 'DEF', 'BBB', '01', 1);

insert into test_01 (CODE_ID, NAME, HEAD_NAME, HEAD_RANK, REPORT_TO_CODE)
values (3, 'GHI', 'ZZZ', '02', 1);

insert into test_01 (CODE_ID, NAME, HEAD_NAME, HEAD_RANK, REPORT_TO_CODE)
values (4, 'JFK', 'XXX', '10', 2);

commit;
```

Our final Output need to stored as an hierarchial structure as shown below.

| Code_ID | Name | Head_Name | Head_Rank | L1_Code | L2_Code | L3_Code | .. | L12_Code | R_ID | LVL_CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | XYZ | 07 |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | ABC | XYZ | 07 | 2 |  |  |  |  | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | ABC | XYZ | 07 | 2 | 4 |  |  |  | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | ABC | XYZ | 07 | 3 |  |  |  |  | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | DEF | BBB | 01 |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | DEF | BBB | 01 | 4 |  |  |  |  | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | GHI | ZZZ | 02 |  |  |  |  |  | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | JFK | XXX | 10 |  |  |  |  |  | 4 | 0 |

No one reports to 3 or 4, so they have only one level.
Here, R_ID -> Takes the last CODE_ID of the hierarchy.
LVL_CNT -> Takes the Maximum number of hierarchial count the R_ID has with respect to the main CODE_ID.

All the reportees to main code, need to be traced back with a level count. The Max can be 12.

We have developed using multiple unions but that has made the process very slow as we deal with lots of data on monthly basis.
**Sample Code:**

```
SELECT
           T01.CODE_ID
       ,   T01.NAME
       ,   T01.HEAD_NAME
       ,   T01.HEAD_RANK
       ,   NULL as L1_CODE
       ,   NULL as L2_CODE
       ,   NULL as L3_CODE
       ,   T01.CODE_ID
       ,   0
      FROM    test_01     T01
UNION
SELECT
           T01.REPORT_TO_CODE
       ,   TT.NAME
       ,   TT.HEAD_NAME
       ,   TT.HEAD_RANK
       ,   T01.CODE_ID as L1_CODE
       ,   NULL as L2_CODE
       ,   NULL as L3_CODE
       ,   T01.CODE_ID
       ,   1
      FROM    test_01     T01
            , test_01     TT
      WHERE T01.REPORT_TO_CODE = TT.CODE_ID
        AND T01.REPORT_TO_CODE <> T01.CODE_ID
UNION
SELECT
           T01.REPORT_TO_CODE
       ,   TT.NAME
       ,   TT.HEAD_NAME
       ,   TT.HEAD_RANK
       ,   T01.CODE_ID as L1_CODE
       ,   T02.CODE_ID as L2_CODE
       ,   NULL as L3_CODE
       ,   T02.CODE_ID
       ,   2
      FROM    test_01     T01
            , test_01     T02
            , test_01     TT
      WHERE T01.REPORT_TO_CODE = TT.CODE_ID
        AND T02.REPORT_TO_CODE =  T01.CODE_ID
        AND T01.REPORT_TO_CODE <> T01.CODE_ID
        AND T02.REPORT_TO_CODE <> T02.CODE_ID
UNION
SELECT
           T01.REPORT_TO_CODE
       ,   TT.NAME
       ,   TT.HEAD_NAME
       ,   TT.HEAD_RANK
       ,   T01.CODE_ID as L1_CODE
       ,   T02.CODE_ID as L2_CODE
       ,   T03.CODE_ID as L3_CODE
       ,   T03.CODE_ID
       ,   3
      FROM    test_01     T01
            , test_01     T02
            , test_01     T03
            , test_01     TT
      WHERE T01.REPORT_TO_CODE = TT.CODE_ID
        AND T02.REPORT_TO_CODE = T01.CODE_ID
        AND T03.REPORT_TO_CODE = T02.CODE_ID
        AND T01.REPORT_TO_CODE <> T01.CODE_ID
        AND T02.REPORT_TO_CODE <> T02.CODE_ID
        AND T03.REPORT_TO_CODE <> T03.CODE_ID
```

I would like to know if there is any easier way to achieve the same result using connect by prior or maybe joins with less unions then I would be very happy and thankful.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what your data represents, what the definitions of the columns are or how you arrived at the resultant dataset. You talk about having developed "multiple unions". Are you able to share an example of your code? This would greatly increase your chances of receiving an that you will find useful.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. Since the main code is in server side, I cannot copy it in my personal machine.
Let me try to share a sample of the code used.

Comment: Sorry because of character limitations I am unable to share the sample code. Is there any other way to send the message to you?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for your table (note: this should be a minimal example so it does not have to be a replica of your system but just the minimal to hold your data); the DML (`INSERT`) statements for your sample data; and an explanation of what your expected output means.

Comment: I have edited the question to provide a few extra information. I hope this makes the query a bit more logical. But the solution provided by you works. Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH rsqfc ( code_id, name, head_name, head_rank, report_to_code, l1_code, l2_code, l3_code, r_id, lvl_cnt ) AS (
  SELECT code_id,
         name,
         head_name,
         head_rank,
         report_to_code,
         CAST( NULL AS NUMBER ),
         CAST( NULL AS NUMBER ),
         CAST( NULL AS NUMBER ),
         code_id,
         0
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT r.code_id,
         r.name,
         r.head_name,
         r.head_rank,
         r.report_to_code,
         CASE lvl_cnt
         WHEN 0
         THEN t.code_id
         ELSE r.l1_code
         END,
         CASE lvl_cnt
         WHEN 1
         THEN t.code_id
         ELSE r.l2_code
         END,
         CASE lvl_cnt
         WHEN 2
         THEN t.code_id
         ELSE r.l3_code
         END,
         t.code_id,
         lvl_cnt + 1
  FROM   table_name t
         INNER JOIN rsqfc r
         ON ( r.r_id = t.report_to_code )
)
SELECT *
FROM   rsqfc
ORDER BY code_id, l1_code NULLS FIRST, l2_code NULLS FIRST, l3_code NULLS FIRST;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Code_ID, Name, Head_Name, Head_Rank, Report_To_Code ) AS
SELECT 1, 'ABC', 'XYZ', '07', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'DEF', 'BBB', '01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'GHI', 'ZZZ', '02', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'JFK', 'XXX', '10', 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CODE_ID | NAME | HEAD_NAME | HEAD_RANK | REPORT_TO_CODE | L1_CODE | L2_CODE | L3_CODE | R_ID | LVL_CNT
> ------: | :--- | :-------- | :-------- | -------------: | ------: | ------: | ------: | ---: | ------:
>       1 | ABC  | XYZ       | 07        |           null |    null |    null |    null |    1 |       0
>       1 | ABC  | XYZ       | 07        |           null |       2 |    null |    null |    2 |       1
>       1 | ABC  | XYZ       | 07        |           null |       2 |       4 |    null |    4 |       2
>       1 | ABC  | XYZ       | 07        |           null |       3 |    null |    null |    3 |       1
>       2 | DEF  | BBB       | 01        |              1 |    null |    null |    null |    2 |       0
>       2 | DEF  | BBB       | 01        |              1 |       4 |    null |    null |    4 |       1
>       3 | GHI  | ZZZ       | 02        |              1 |    null |    null |    null |    3 |       0
>       4 | JFK  | XXX       | 10        |              2 |    null |    null |    null |    4 |       0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6c379ea917b589a4696fc1ea836ab92f)*

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have tried your solution and everything seems to fine, except for the LVL_CNT.
CODE_ID | NAME | HEAD_NAME | HEAD_RANK | REPORT_TO_CODE | L1_CODE | L2_CODE | L3_CODE | R_ID | LVL_CNT
------: | :--- | :-------- | :-------- | -------------: | ------: | ------: | ------: | ---: | ------:
      1 | ABC  | XYZ       | 07        |           null |       2 |       4 |    null |    4 |       1(should be 2)
      1 | ABC  | XYZ       | 07        |           null |       3 |    null |    null |    3 |       2(should be 1)

Comment: So I just remodified the last part as
SELECT code_id,
       name,
       head_name,
       head_rank,
       report_to_code,
       l1_code,
       l2_code,
       l3_code,
       r_id,
       lvl -1 as lvl_cnt
FROM   rsqfc
ORDER BY code_id, l1_code NULLS FIRST, l2_code NULLS FIRST, l3_code NULLS FIRST;
It solves my problem

Comment: @spartacus Updated, assuming that `lvl_cnt` is measuring the depth descended through the hierarchy. In future, it would be better if your question includes all the details of what the columns mean and how they are calculated as I had made an initial assumption about what `lvl_cnt` was and I do not think it was correct.

Comment: Sure :). Can't thank enough for the help.